# How to get the Chat or Group name of Incoming Telegram message using Telethon?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I have this code

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events

with TelegramClient('name', api_id, api_hash) as client:
   @client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern=pattern))
   async def handler(event):
      await event.reply("Here should be the Chat or Group name")
```

How to implement this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if we are talking only about groups/channels

```
chat_from = event.chat if event.chat else (await event.get_chat()) # telegram MAY not send the chat enity
chat_title = chat_from.title
```

Else (If we want to get the full name of chat entities, including Users):

```
from telethon import utils

chat_from = event.chat if event.chat else (await event.get_chat()) # telegram MAY not send the chat enity
chat_title = utils.get_display_name(chat_from)
```

get_display_name() actually gets a name that you would see. Works for types `User, Channel, Chat`
That method shall not have `await`

Comment: Worth mentioning `event.get_chat()` won't make a request if `event.chat is not None and not event.chat.min` (I believe the title is always present even with `min`, so this approach is the best).